# Adding react build files to a Git repository

Tags: django, reactjs, git, npm

I am trying to add the build files which are created by `npm run build` in a React App, to a Git repository.

The files generated by `npm run build` is getting directly used by my backend server on Django. And my backend(in Django) and the frontend(in React) are two different Git repositories.

Here is the problem I am facing.

1. Every time I run `npm run build` it creates new files with different hashes. If I keep on adding all the files, the size of my git repository will increase. I tried removing older files completely from git by running `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf build/static' HEAD`. But since this rewrites the history, I'll have to use `git push` with `--force` every time, which doesn't feel right.
2. I can avoid adding static files all together by creating the build directly on the server. This will be helpful, but everyone working on the back end will have to build the static files locally, which means they'll have to install node and react, which might be cumbersome for the back end developers.

Is there a better way of doing this? How should I solve this?

Comment: Django should be dealing with the entire stack. Even with separate frontend and backend teams, integrating backend code with frontend should be happening constantly, otherwise, there wouldn’t be much need for Django, in MY opinion. There are methods of integratin hb React with Django, but you shouldn’t make it separate in Git repo. You can have two branches for backend and frontend, but the master branch should be all together.

Comment: So I’d recommend this: https://hackernoon.com/serving-react-and-django-together-2089645046e4

Comment: @Yoomama thanks for the comment. I believe the blog is regarding local development. I am more concerned about the production build, where I need to serve the final build from react in the django app. Also branching out backend and frontend isn't a good solution according to me.

Comment: I don't use React, when you create a new React project, there should be a .gitignore: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/.gitignore I noticed that you shouldn't be pushing your `build` directory into the Git repo. This should fix the problem, and you can then stick to one master branch.

Answer (score 0):

Follow FaceBook's create-react-app repo: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/.gitignore

In their gitignore, they explicitly do not push the build directory. This should clear up those hashes issues.